# Transendental number

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$

are transcendental numbers.

$\gamma ={\alpha}^{\beta}$

When $\gamma$ is transcendental?
Is it depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

I know $\gamma$ is not
always transcendental.
For example :
$e^{\ln{2}}=2$

Comment: I’d guess the best one can say is “most of the time.”

Comment: If the answer is not “always”, then it depends on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, right?!

Comment: I think that only very special cases can be decided.

Comment: For any transcendental $\alpha$ there is a countably infinite set of transcendental $\beta$s such that $\gamma=\alpha^\beta$ is algebraic (with subsets of these $\beta$s leading to rational or integer $\gamma$s)